# Is there a reason why margins are not working in this case for my header?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ MAIN */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Header */

.header-main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(181, 34, 159), rgb(224, 21, 186));
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgb(43, 12, 43);
}

#header-troll {
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}

#header-title {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#header-course-project {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

#header-dog{
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

This is what I have so far for my code.

[image]

This is what it looks like and I'm just very confused on why the "React Course - Project 3" is not going all the way to the right? If anyone can help that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: proberly because of `#header-dog { margin-left: auto; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much easier way to keep the two groups each at one end is by using flex-box properties:

First, organize your HTML elements, grouping #header-troll and #header-title in a div, and #header-course-project and #header-dog and another one, like that:

```html
<div class="header-main">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div id="header-troll"><img /></div>
        <div id="header-title">Meme Generator</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
        <div id="header-course-project">React Course - Project 3</div>
        <div id="header-dog"><img /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, add `justify-content: space-between` on header-main class properties. This way the header-main children will be evenly distributed in the line. As it has only two children, the first one (.left-side) will be on the start line, and the second one (.right-side) will be on the end line.

```css
.header-main {
    /* your code */
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Create left-side and right-side classes

```css
.left-side {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.right-side {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

You can use the `gap` to define the space between the elements instead of defining margins for each one.
```

References: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/